# Rails Cancancan - authorizing nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have the following models:

```
class Party
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :party_co_hosts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :party_co_hosts
  has_many :co_hosts, through: :party_co_hosts

class CoHost
  belongs_to :party
  belongs_to :co_host, foreign_key: :user_id

class User
```

A party should belong to a user (the host) and the host can assign co-hosts who should be able to edit details on the party but not add/delete co-hosts. I'm struggling to define that ability in Cancancan.

```
can :update, Party, user_id: user.id
```

This gives the host carte blanche to do what they want to the party - that's good.

```
can :update, Party do |p|
  p.co_hosts.include? user
end
```

This would give a co-host the ability to edit the party, which is also good, but I don't want that to include the nested `party_co_hosts` association.

Should I remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and force `party_co_hosts` to be created through a separate controller rather than allowing the nested association in the parent? Other ideas that I'm just missing?

Answer (score 1):

just an idea probably can help, I'm thinking new design for your problem

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :parties, through: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :party
end

class Party < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through: :roles
end
```

**role table has field user_id, party_id and title as string**, title content can be as a guest or co-host, if role as co-host then the user can edit the party model if as a guest they can only read etc

and then for checking authorization you can use [role base authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization)